# Runtime DLL issues with Haskell and Awesomium

Tags: haskell, dll, cabal, awesomium

I am trying to run a Haskell program that depends on the [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) library. I've compiled it but ran into the following issue at runtime:

[image: Cannot find procedure start address...]

Roughly translated, it says that the procedure start address for awe_history_entry_get_visit_count cannot be found in the DLL file [path to my executable].

It seems like it is trying to load that symbol from my program rather than `awesomium.dll`.

- I'm on Windows 10
- I'm using [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) as my build tool
- The program is 32-bit (i386), because that is the only architecture Awesomium supports
- I've referenced the DLLs I need in the `extra-libraries` field in the `.cabal` file

Any help or hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually managed to solve it on my own. Turns out I was trying to link to a more recent version of the Awesomium SDK.

Having downgraded to Awesomium 1.6.5 and replaced the DLLs in my build folder with the older ones, I am now able to initialise the `WebCore` and create `WebViews`.

Unfortunately, I still haven't been able to render any HTML (stuck on loading), but that's for another question...